# dockerfile can't be ran

Tags: php, docker, windows-10, apache2

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.5-apache

COPY sites-enabled.tgz /root/sites-enabled.tgz

RUN cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled && \
    tar xvf /root/sites-enabled.tgz
```

I have a number of sites that need to be configured and I figure the easiest way to go about configuring them is to just copy the config files for the sites into the appropriate directories. Unfortunately I'm not able to do so.

I do `docker build -t mywebsite .` and then `docker run -d mywebsite`. Both of those commands appear to run just fine. The last one gives me a hex encoded string. But then when I do `docker ps` I don't see any machines running.

Typically, the files in sites-enabled are symlinks to sites-available. idk if that's the case in every case but if it is then it seems like it might be necessary to copy the sites-available sites over as well. eg.

```
FROM php:5.5-apache

COPY sites-available.tgz /root/sites-available.tgz
COPY sites-enabled.tgz /root/sites-enabled.tgz

RUN cd /etc/apache2/sites-available && \
    tar xvf /root/sites-available.tgz

RUN cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled && \
    tar xvf /root/sites-enabled.tgz
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. With sites-available.tgz it does but not sites-enabled.tgz.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the container does what you say, it makes a copy on the file and puts into the container, then it goes to the directory and finally it decompress the file, and that's it.
You're not declaring a `CMD` command which will initialize apache, or do anything, so your container will not stay up unless you do that

try putting this at the end of the dockerfile
`CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND`

let me know how it goes

Comment: Same thing happens. The docker container ceases to show up when I do `docker ps` immediately after `docker run -d mywebsite`. And, if that had worked then it'd behoove the question of why that was needed when `sites-enabled.tgz` was being copied but not when `sites-available.tgz` was being copied.

Comment: try to run `docker ps -a` to show all your stoped containers, then get the container id of the last one (it's at the top), then run `docker logs <container id> so you can see what is happening`

Comment: `docker logs` was what I needed. I guess the config file had a directive in it that Apache didn't support (at least not without mod_ssl). Thanks!